# Django Forms cannot render Radio Buttons

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sorry I am very new to Django. I read a lot of answers but cannot make it work. I am missing something

This is my forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Post
    from django.utils.translation import gettext as _



    class EventsForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        CHOICES=[('select1','select 1'), ('select2','select 2')]
        model = Post
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('form-title')}),
            'type_id': forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect),
        }
        fields = ('title', 'type_id', 'post_date', )
```

I want to have Radio Buttons for **type_id**

I am getting the error

```
'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

Can you explain me what I am doing wrong :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
    class EventsForm(forms.ModelForm):
      CHOICES=(('select1','select 1'), ('select2','select 2'))
      type_id = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
      class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'type_id', 'post_date', )
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me what is the difference and way in this way it works ?

Comment: Cause the 'widget' is forms.RadioSelect not choiceField... the last is a field

Comment: @user43506 For anybody still wondering, `forms.ChoiceField` / `forms.TypedChoiceField` was moved from `Meta` class constructor to `EventsForm` class constructor.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas should be to ModelForm instead

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing form fields and widgets. The things you specify in the `widgets` dict have to actually be widgets.

```
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('form-title')}),
        'type_id': forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES),
    }
```